# Find and _modify_ text using regular expressions

Tags: sed

I have a lot of files like "some_text some_number.jpg", for example:

```
blabla 1.ext
blabla 22.ext
blabla 323.ext
```

And I need to rename thies to "some_text some_number-some_number+1.jpg":

```
blabla 1-2.ext
blabla 22-23.ext
blabla 323-324.ext
```

How can I use \1 like integer variable?

Of couse this code is wrong:

```
    for fn in *; do new_fn=$(echo $fn|sed 's/ \([0-9]*\)/ \1-\1\++/'); mv $fn $new_fn; done
```

```
blabla 1-1++.ext
blabla 22-22++.ext
blabla 323-323++.ext
```

Comment: First, check your script with shellcheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use \1 like integer variable?

It is impossible to use anything as integer in sed. It is impossible to do arithmetic operations in sed. Use something else. Bash, Python, Perl, etc.

Try, untested, however should give you a hint what algorithm you might want to implement:

```
for fn in *; do
   # split on space and dot!
   IFS=' .' read -r pre num post <<<"$fn"
   newnum=$((num + 1))
   echo mv "$fn" "$pre $newnum.$post"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -E 's/(.* )([0-9]+)(\.ext)/echo "\1\2-$((\2+1))\3"/e' file
```